# Rotational invariance of Laplacian operator

Tags: rotations, laplacian, differential-operators

I was reading in Wikipedia about [Rotational invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_invariance) and noticed that the two-dimensional **Laplacian operator** $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}$ is thought to be invariant under rotations. I was trying to prove this for a given function $f\in \mathbb{R}^2$ but I couldn't find a way.

Let's assume we have a 2D given function $f(x,y)$ in Cartesian coordinates. I am trying to show that the **Laplacian operator is rotational invariant**, which means that:

$$\nabla^{2}_{xy} f = f_{xx}+f_{yy}=f_{x^\prime x^\prime}+f_{y^\prime y^\prime }=\nabla^{2}_{x^\prime y^\prime} f$$

Which is the right way to approach this?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question a while back https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258431/laplacian-and-orthogonal-operator Bu this treats the general $n$-dimensional case directly

Comment: @peek-a-boo Hmm this post seems a bit more complicated. I am still confused. Would it be easy for you to write down an answer for my case? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this 2-dimensional case, everything is much simpler, I agree. In fact you can even write down explicitly what a general rotation looks like. So, suppose you have two sets of coordinates; $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$, where one is obtained from another by a rotation, say of angle $\phi$:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
u &= x\cos \phi - y \sin \phi \\
v &= x \sin \phi + y \cos \phi
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now, using the chain rule, we find that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} &= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial }{\partial u}  + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v} \\
&= \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial}{\partial u} + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}
\end{align}
and similarly,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} &= -\sin \phi \dfrac{\partial}{\partial u} + \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}
\end{align}
Now, try to calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ similarly, and then add them up. You should find in a few lines of algebra (after using $\sin^2 + \cos ^2 = 1$ a couple of times) that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial v^2}
\end{align}

---

**Edit: Answering Question in comments**

We have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) 
\end{align}
Now, temporarily define $g$ as 
\begin{align}
g:= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial f }{\partial u}  + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2} &= \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\
&= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} \\
&= \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u} + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} \\
&= \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial }{\partial u} \left( \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right) + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial }{\partial v} \left( \cos \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \right) \\
&= \cos^2 \phi \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial u^2} + 2\cos \phi \sin \phi \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial u \partial v} + \sin^2 \phi \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial v^2}
\end{align}
where in the last line, I expanded everything, and used equality of mixed partials. If you do a similar thing with $y$, you'll get a $-2 \sin \phi \cos \phi$ term instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!Nice and easy explanation. Now It makes a lot more sense to me. Could you please give me a link about the certain chain rule you mention (with just the partial derivatives)? Because I am not familiar with it. In particular, I have seen alternative forms of the chain rule and would like to make it more clear.

Comment: @RogFed I'm sure you've seen the following version of the chain rule (or something similar): if $f = f(u,v)$ and $u = u(x,y)$ and $v = v(x,y)$ then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \cdot \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.  Now, simply "remove" $f$ from everything, so that we consider this as an "equality of differential operators". This is how I wrote the first equation.

Comment: I got that. I am just finding difficulties in calculating the second partial derivatives: $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ . I must be doing something wrong with the chain rule,I guess. Could you include one of these calculations to your answer? It would be really helpful. I'm gonna accept the answer as well.

Comment: @RogFed how about you show your calculations, then I can tell you where you've gone wrong/ how to correct it. I suggest putting the $f$ back everywhere to make everything obvious.

Comment: I am not havving difficulties with the $f$ notation. I just don't get how to apply the  partial derivative on the first chain rule. I don't actually know how to use the distributive property with the derivatives, so I haven't yet managed to end up with something to show.

Comment: I think I figured it out now. You made it way too clear and simple! Thanks a lot for your time! Will upvote the answer as well when I get more reputation.

Comment: How can we be sure that equality of the mixed partials is valid here?

Comment: @RogFed When talking about taking Laplacians, we usually assume the function is atleast twice differentiable (or even twice continuously differentiable). Under this assumption, the equality of mixed partials is valid. Also, as long as you have enough regularity to apply the chain rule twice (which is certainly the case if we assume twice-differentiable functions), then try redoing the same calculation I showed; the exact same cross-terms will cancel when you add $\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}$.

Comment: I did the calculations without the assumption of the equality of mixed partials and still end up with the same result. So, even if it's valid, it seems that it's not necessary to be used right here.

Answer (score 1):

A rotation from one system of Cartesian coordinates $x_i$ to another with coordinates $y_J$ satisfies $x_i=R_{iJ}y_J$, and hence a chain rule of the form $dx_i=R_{iJ}dy_J$, where we [sum over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and the [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) $R$ satisfies $RR^T=I$, or in terms of the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)$R_{iJ}R_{kJ}=\delta_{ik}$. First derivatives obey$$R_{iJ}\partial_ifdy^J=\partial_i fdx^i=df=\partial_Jfdy^J\implies R_{ij}\partial_i=\partial_J.$$So$$\partial_J\partial_L=R_{iJ}R_{kL}\partial_i\partial_k\implies\nabla^{\prime2}=\partial_J\partial_J=R_{iJ}R_{kJ}\partial_i\partial_k=\partial_i\partial_i=\nabla^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!