# Notations for invariance of Laplacian under orthogonal transformations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, laplacian

Let $ f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R $ be in $ C^2 $ and $ R \in O(n) $ be an orthogonal transformation. My understanding of what invariance of the Laplacian under orthogonal transformations (e.g. rotations) means, is that

$ \triangle f = (\triangle f) \circ R. \qquad \qquad $ (1)

This is for instance how I understand the proof for the simple case of rotations in two dimensions by peek-a-boo given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632836/rotational-invariance-of-laplacian-operator). If $ x \in \mathbb R^n $ and $ R(x)=u $, then (1) means that $ \triangle f(x) = \triangle f(u) $.

However, often I find the following definition instead

$ (\triangle f) \circ R = \triangle (f \circ R). \qquad \qquad $ (2)

I can't figure out what the rhs of this actually means and whether or not (2) is equivalent to (1).

What is $ \big[ \triangle (f \circ R) \big](x), \quad x \in \mathbb R^n $?

Comment: No, (1) is not what rotational-invariance of Laplacian means, and it's not what I proved in my answer there. (1) is actually false, just look at $f(x,y)=x^3$ and $R(u,v)=(-v,u)$. Then, $(\Delta f)(x,y)=6x$, but $[(\Delta f)\circ R](u,v)=(\Delta f)(R(u,v))=(\Delta f)(-v,u)=-6v$. In other words, $\Delta f$ takes a tuple and spits out $6$ times the first entry, while $(\Delta f)\circ R$ takes a tuple and spits out $-6$ times the second entry. Clearly different functions. Statement (2) is the correct interpretation, and it's what I proved in the link (and the link inside the link).

Comment: It's not clear why you say you can't figure out what the rhs of (2) means. $f$ is a $C^2$ function $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, and $R:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal (in particular linear, in particular $C^{\infty}$) so the composite function $f\circ R:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is $C^2$ so you can calculate its Laplacian. Further, you can relate partial derivatives of $f\circ R$ with partials of $f$ and partials of $R$ evaluated at correct points, using the chain rule. It turns out $\Delta (f\circ R)= (\Delta f)\circ R$.

Comment: in simple words, (2) is saying "if you find the Laplacian and then rotate" (i.e the LHS of $2$) the result is the same as "rotating first and then finding Laplacian" (the RHS of (2)). Or even more abstractly, given an orthogonal $R$, define $T_R$ to be the map on functions given by composition: $T_R(f):= f\circ R$. Then, the statement is that $T_R$ and $\Delta$ commute.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, thanks. Must be I have a severe blackout with this issue. Can you possibly show me how in your linked proof you proved (2)? I don't see that.

Comment: go to the link, and click on the link which I posted in that comments section.

Comment: The point is basically to use chain rule twice: the second derivative formula in general is $D^2(f\circ T)_x[h,k]=D^2f_{T(x)}[DT_x(h),DT_x(k)]+Df_{T(x)}\left(D^2T_x[h,k]\right)$. For a linear $T$, the first derivative $DT_x=T$ and second derivative $D^2T_x$ vanishes, so the second term is zero. Hence, $D^2(f\circ T)_x[h,k]=D^2f_{T(x)}[T(h),T(k)]$. The Laplacian is by definition the trace, so plug in $h=k=e_i$ and sum over $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$.